# Software tools for Savage Worlds: Showdown unit building?

Tags: tool-recommendation, savage-worlds-showdown

I recently got into this version of Savage Worlds, and it seems helluva fun to play with friends, as sometimes we have wanted to make our very own minis wargame... However the rules on how to calculate unit points are convoluted and hard to use.

I've been surfing the webs and found a "handly" Excel-based troop builder, but whenever values are inserted it won't calculate them – I have to fill in the troop cards manually. So that's not so handy.

Is there any working software for building troops on a PC?

Comment: I *think* this should be tagged differently, as it isn't strictly a core Savage Worlds thing

Comment: Not a full answer, but you might want to check out http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the time of this writing, the only tool for building Savage Worlds Showdown characters is the official Excel spreadsheet from Pinnacle.

However, [Wild Card Creator](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/657350477/wild-card-creator), a Savage Worlds character creator program, had a Kickstarter stretch goal for adding support for Savage Worlds Showdown at some point after the final release (the date listed in the stretch goal was rather optimistic). So there will be another option, but for now, the official Excel spreadsheet is it.

(Full disclsoure: I am the author of Wild Card Creator)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the kickstarter page (still up as of this writing), the Wild Card Creator project by Thunderforge looks really nice. Though I am sure it cannot compare, there is also a web-based opensource project (which I am a contributor to) called  [Showdown Troop Builder, available on github](https://github.com/retroredge/showdown-troop-builder%20%22available%20on%20GitHub%22.).